# xamarin android JsonConvert.DeserializeObject is null

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, json.net

I am developing a Xamarin Android App, with Visual Studio 2012.

I am calling a Activity2 from Activity1 and I a passing a Class Instance.

In Activity2 under

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

I get the value... like this

```
 Tecnico tecnico = new Tecnico();
 tecnico = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Tecnico>(Intent.GetStringExtra("Tecnico"));

Int16 id = tecnico.ID;

 if (tecnico.ID == null)
{}
```

The class is called Técnico and It have a Property called ID...

The problem is that the line

```
Int16 id = tecnico.ID;
```

return the correct value...126, but when I ask

```
if (tecnico.ID == null)
```

it is always true...

How it is posible?

Thabks

Comment: a value type can't be null

Comment: Can you share the `Tecnico` class or otherwise provide a [mcve]?